# DateTime::Format::CLDR issues parsing long Czech dates

Tags: perl, datetime, encoding, cldr

I am trying to parse Czech dates using CLDR long format as specified by `DateTime::Locale::cs_CZ`. I see no obvious reason why it should fail.

```
my $locale2 = DateTime::Locale->load('cs_CZ');
my $cldr5 = DateTime::Format::CLDR->new(
    pattern     => $locale2->date_format_long,
    locale      => $locale2,
    );

print $cldr5->pattern, "\n";
print $cldr5->parse_datetime('17. listopad 1989');
```

The output is

```
d. MMMM y

Use of uninitialized value in print at ./test-cldr.pl line 54.
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it not parse the date?

**UPDATE**

This is what I have actually been using to test this on command line:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MDateTime -MDateTime::Format::CLDR -wle'
    local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { print( Carp::longmess (shift) ); };
    $x="19. září 1979";
    my $loc = DateTime::Locale->load("cs_CZ");
    print Dumper($loc), "\n";
    my $cldr = DateTime::Format::CLDR->new(
       pattern=>$loc->date_format_long, locale=>$loc, on_error => "croak");
    print Dumper($cldr->parse_datetime($x));
'
```

This is the output I get:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'en_language' => 'Czech',
                 'native_territory' => "\x{10c}esk\x{e1} republika",
                 'en_territory' => 'Czech Republic',
                 'native_language' => "\x{10d}e\x{161}tina",
                 'default_time_format_length' => 'medium',
                 'id' => 'cs_CZ',
                 'native_complete_name' => "\x{10d}e\x{161}tina \x{10c}esk\x{e1} republika",
                 'default_date_format_length' => 'medium',
                 'en_complete_name' => 'Czech Czech Republic'
               }, 'DateTime::Locale::cs_CZ' );


Could not get datetime for 19. září 1979 (Error marked by 'HERE-->'): '19.  HERE-->září 1979' at -e line 7.
 at /usr/share/perl5/DateTime/Format/CLDR.pm line 965.
    DateTime::Format::CLDR::_local_croak(DateTime::Format::CLDR=HASH(0x166bcd8), "Could not get datetime for 19. z\x{c3}\x{a1}\x{c5}\x{99}\x{c3}\x{ad} 1979 (Error marked by "...) called at /usr/share/perl5/DateTime/Format/CLDR.pm line 558
    DateTime::Format::CLDR::__ANON__("z\x{c3}\x{a1}\x{c5}\x{99}\x{c3}\x{ad} 1979") called at /usr/share/perl5/DateTime/Format/CLDR.pm line 582
    DateTime::Format::CLDR::parse_datetime(DateTime::Format::CLDR=HASH(0x166bcd8), "19. z\x{c3}\x{a1}\x{c5}\x{99}\x{c3}\x{ad} 1979") called at -e line 7

Could not get datetime for 19. září 1979 (Error marked by 'HERE-->'): '19.  HERE-->září 1979' at -e line 7.
```

Comment: You define `$locale2` but use `$locale`. Do you `use strict;` and `use warnings;` ?

Comment: @glennjackman: You are right. Unfortunately, it still fails even after fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 17. listopad 1989

`print(Dumper($self->_build_pattern()));` gives a peek into what the module expects. It outputs the following in this case.

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            qr/(3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9])/,
            'd',
            1
          ],
          '\\.',
          '\\s+',
          [
            "(listopadu|\x{10d}ervence|prosince|b\x{159}ezna|kv\x{11b}tna|\x{10d}ervna|ledna|\x{fa}nora|dubna|srpna|\x{159}\x{ed}jna|z\x{e1}\x{159}\x{ed})",
            'M',
            4
          ],
          '\\s+',
          [
            qr/(-?\d{1,4})/,
            'y',
            1
          ]
        ];
```

It expects `listopadu`, but not `listopad`. I don't know anything about Czech, but the module's behaviour appears to be [correct](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Czech_Language/Months_and_Dates). You could "fix up" the dates before parsing them.

```
$date_string =~ s/\blistopad\b\K/u/;
```

### 19. září 1979

You're not actually passing `září` (`"z\x{e1}\x{159}\x{ed}"`). You're passing its UTF-8 encoding (`"z\x{c3}\x{a1}\x{c5}\x{99}\x{c3}\x{ad}"`). Add `use utf8;` to tell Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: OK, but the first test I have posted is not using anything outside ASCII.

Comment: I apparently suck at my own mother tongue more than I thought! I also suck at making proper SO questions. :) I would give you 10 upvotes if I could. You were right on all accounts in the end. The genitive form of the month _is_ actually used in the source where I am taking the date from.

Comment: No worries. That executable bit you added was awesome :) I wish all questions were executable.